# Compact way to write $\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)-\cos(\beta-\gamma)$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a more compact way to write
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)-\cos(\beta-\gamma)$$
or is this a ``minimal'' expression?

I mention that, by more compact, I mean with the least
number of terms.

Comment: apply formula of difference of cos

Comment: Almost a joke (not totally though)... You should define what *the least number of terms* means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Answer:

$\sin(\alpha/2)\sin(\beta-\gamma+\alpha/2)$

```
$\sin(\alpha/2)\sin(\beta-\gamma+\alpha/2)$
```

43 characters, 4 terms for additions/subtractions.

Your expression $\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)-\cos(\beta-\gamma)$

```
$\cos(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)-\cos(\beta-\gamma)$
```

used 46 characters, 5 terms for additions/subtractions.

If using integral, we can have

$\int_\alpha^0\sin(\beta-\gamma+x){\rm d}x$

```
$\int_\alpha^0\sin(\beta-\gamma+x){\rm d}x$
```

used 43 characters, 3 terms for additions/subtractions.